# Remote annotation not working in edit mode

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Now i have an issue in remote annotation in edit mode not work but in add mode working eight .... in edit mode if i focus in text box that i made remote annotation in it then focus out the text box and press submit the form working right in edit mode but if i don't focus in text box the form submit even if i enter invalid data and remote annotation action is called after submitting !!!

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <label for="form-username" class="  control-label">
    <%=Dashboard.App_GlobalResources.ui.Views.Shared.SharedStrings.ID%>
    <span class="required" aria-required="true">* </span>
  </label>
  <div class=" ">
    <div class="input-icon right">
      <i class="fa"></i>
      <%:Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.username, new { @id = "form-username", @name = "SSN",@class="form-control" })%>
      <%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.username)%>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

in model

```
[CustomRequired]
[MaxAvaLength(20)]
[Remote("usernameForCountry", "Validation")]
public string username
{
    get { return _username; }
    set { _username = value; }
}
```

validation function

```
public JsonResult usernameForCountry(string username)
{
    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Unclear what your asking. You current `usernameForCountry()` method just returns `true` which indicates the property is valid so there will never be any validation errors. What are you really trying to so?

Answer (score 0):

If user exists you have to return `false` not `true`:

```
public JsonResult usernameForCountry(string username)
{
     if (_userManager.IsUserExist(username)) return Json(false);
     return Json(true);
}
```